# when I train my network, The same number appears periodically on my my training acc ， I don't konow the error come from

Tags: python, pytorch

**this is my train.py**
I use dice loss for my network ,**outputs** size is [4,2,224,224] where 4 means batchsize, 2 means channels, 224 means h and w .output_c1 size is [4,224,224] ,labels size is [4,224,224] too.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
from model import U_net
import visdom
from dataset import driveDateset
from torch import optim
from Dice_loss import DiceLoss
from Dice_loss import MulticlassDiceLoss
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DATA_DIRECTORY = "F:\\experiment_code\\U-net\\DRIVE\\training"
    DATA_LIST_PATH = "F:\\experiment_code\\U-net\DRIVE\\training\\images_id.txt"
    Batch_size = 4
    epochs = 100
    #MEAN = (104.008, 116.669, 122.675)
    dst = driveDateset(DATA_DIRECTORY, DATA_LIST_PATH)

    # Initialize model
    device = torch.device("cuda")
    model = U_net()
    model.to(device)

    #Initial optimizer
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
    best_acc, best_epoch =0, 0
    global_step = 0
    start_time = time.time()
    viz = visdom.Visdom()

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        running_corrects = 0
        since_epoch = time.time()
        trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dst, batch_size=Batch_size) #,shuffle =True
        for step, data in enumerate(trainloader):
            imgs, labels, _, _ = data

            imgs, labels = imgs.to(device), labels.to(device)
            labels = labels.float()
            # labels = labels / 255.0
            # labels[labels > 0.5] = 1.
            # labels[labels < 0.5] = 0.
            # imgs = imgs / 255.0
            model.train()
            outputs = model(imgs)   # output  B * C * H *W
            output_c1 = outputs[:,1,:,:] # C are 2 channels


            # Dice loss
            binary_output_c1 = torch.round(output_c1)
            # Network output visualization
            binary_output_c1_show = binary_output_c1.cpu().detach().numpy().astype(np.uint8)
            plt.figure()
            plt.suptitle('Network visualization output')
            plt.subplot(1, 4, 1)
            plt.imshow(binary_output_c1_show[0,:,:] ),plt.axis('off')
            plt.subplot(1, 4, 2)
            plt.imshow(binary_output_c1_show[1, :, :] ),plt.axis('off')
            plt.subplot(1, 4, 3)
            plt.imshow(binary_output_c1_show[2, :, :] ),plt.axis('off')
            plt.subplot(1, 4, 4)
            plt.imshow(binary_output_c1_show[3, :, :] ),plt.axis('off')
            plt.show()
            plt.pause(0.5)


            #dice = MulticlassDiceLoss()
            dice = DiceLoss()
            loss = dice(binary_output_c1,labels)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            viz.line([loss.item()],[global_step], win='loss', update='append',opts=dict(title='train_loss'))
            running_corrects = torch.sum(binary_output_c1 == labels).float()
            labels_size = labels.size(1) * labels.size(2) * 4
            training_acc = running_corrects / labels_size
            time_elapsed_epoch = time.time() - since_epoch
            print('epoch :', epoch, '\t', 'loss:', loss.item(),'\t','training_acc',training_acc,'\t','{:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format(time_elapsed_epoch // 60, time_elapsed_epoch % 60))
            global_step += 1


    time_elapsed = time.time() - start_time
    print('Training complate in {:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format(time_elapsed // 60, time_elapsed % 60))
```

**my Dice_loss.py is:**

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


class DiceLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DiceLoss, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, input, target):
        N = target.size(0)
        smooth = 1

        input_flat = input.view(N, -1)
        target_flat = target.view(N, -1)
        #target_flat = torch.t(target_flat)

        intersection = input_flat * target_flat

        loss = 2 * (intersection.sum(1) + smooth) / (input_flat.sum(1) + target_flat.sum(1) + smooth)
        loss = 1 - loss.sum() / N

        return loss


class MulticlassDiceLoss(nn.Module):
    """
    requires one hot encoded target. Applies DiceLoss on each class iteratively.
    requires input.shape[0:1] and target.shape[0:1] to be (N, C) where N is
      batch size and C is number of classes
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super(MulticlassDiceLoss, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, input, target, weights=None):

        C = target.shape[1]

        if weights is None:
         weights = torch.ones(C) #uniform weights for all classes

        dice = DiceLoss()
        totalLoss = 0

        for i in range(C):
            diceLoss = dice(input[:, i], target[:, i])
            if weights is not None:
                diceLoss *= weights[i]
            totalLoss += diceLoss

        return totalLoss
```

**I test Data incoming has no problem ,every training data has Traversed. training data and label like this**

[image]

**but when I train my network  ,output picture like this ,**
[image]

**and some result like this :**

```
epoch : 0    loss: -0.8808882236480713   training_acc tensor(0.3331, device='cuda:0')    0m 2s
epoch : 0    loss: -0.478731632232666    training_acc tensor(0.4376, device='cuda:0')    0m 3s
epoch : 0    loss: -0.42925024032592773      training_acc tensor(0.4485, device='cuda:0')    0m 4s
epoch : 0    loss: -0.60923171043396     training_acc tensor(0.4187, device='cuda:0')    0m 5s
epoch : 0    loss: -0.4442058801651001   training_acc tensor(0.4383, device='cuda:0')    0m 6s
epoch : 1    loss: -0.8808882236480713   training_acc tensor(0.3331, device='cuda:0')    0m 1s
epoch : 1    loss: -0.478731632232666    training_acc tensor(0.4376, device='cuda:0')    0m 2s
epoch : 1    loss: -0.42925024032592773      training_acc tensor(0.4485, device='cuda:0')    0m 2s
epoch : 1    loss: -0.60923171043396     training_acc tensor(0.4187, device='cuda:0')    0m 3s
epoch : 1    loss: -0.4442058801651001   training_acc tensor(0.4383, device='cuda:0')    0m 4s
epoch : 2    loss: -0.8808882236480713   training_acc tensor(0.3331, device='cuda:0')    0m 1s
```

**I dont't know how to solve this problem**
I try to use one-hot encoding to transform outputs and crossentropyloss

```
imgs, labels = imgs.to(device), labels.to(device) # imgs size [4,224,224]
criteon = nn.CrossEntropyLoss() #reduce=False
model.train()
outputs = model(imgs)   # output  B * C * H *W
output_c1 = outputs[:,1,:,:] # outputs have 2 channels ,I choose the second channels
Rounding_output_c1 = torch.round(output_c1)
Rounding_output_c11 = torch.stack([(Rounding_output_c1 == i).float() for i in range(256)]) # [4,224,224]-> [256,4,224,224] ,256 means the number of classes
Rounding_output_c11 = Rounding_output_c11.permute(1,0,2,3)   #[256,4,224,224]->[4,256,224,224]
loss = criteon(Rounding_output_c11,labels)
loss.requires_grad = True
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
labels_float = labels.float()
running_corrects = torch.sum(Rounding_output_c1 == labels_float).float()
labels_size = labels.size(1) * labels.size(2) * 4
training_acc = running_corrects / labels_size
```

and get the same phenomenon

```
epoch : 0    loss: 5.2415571212768555    training_acc tensor(0.3103, device='cuda:0')    0m 2s
epoch : 0    loss: 5.228370666503906     training_acc tensor(0.3235, device='cuda:0')    0m 2s
epoch : 0    loss: 5.224219799041748     training_acc tensor(0.3276, device='cuda:0')    0m 2s
epoch : 0    loss: 5.222436428070068     training_acc tensor(0.3294, device='cuda:0')    0m 2s
epoch : 0    loss: 5.2202887535095215    training_acc tensor(0.3316, device='cuda:0')    0m 2s
epoch : 1    loss: 5.2415571212768555    training_acc tensor(0.3103, device='cuda:0')    0m 0s
epoch : 1    loss: 5.22836971282959      training_acc tensor(0.3235, device='cuda:0')    0m 0s
epoch : 1    loss: 5.224219799041748     training_acc tensor(0.3276, device='cuda:0')    0m 0s
epoch : 1    loss: 5.222436428070068     training_acc tensor(0.3294, device='cuda:0')    0m 1s
epoch : 1    loss: 5.2202887535095215    training_acc tensor(0.3316, device='cuda:0')    0m 1s
epoch : 2    loss: 5.2415571212768555    training_acc tensor(0.3103, device='cuda:0')    0m 0s
epoch : 2    loss: 5.22836971282959      training_acc tensor(0.3235, device='cuda:0')    0m 0s
epoch : 2    loss: 5.224219799041748     training_acc tensor(0.3276, device='cuda:0')    0m 0s
epoch : 2    loss: 5.222436428070068     training_acc tensor(0.3294, device='cuda:0')    0m 1s
epoch : 2    loss: 5.2202887535095215    training_acc tensor(0.3316, device='cuda:0')    0m 1s
epoch : 3    loss: 5.2415571212768555    training_acc tensor(0.3103, device='cuda:0')    0m 0s
epoch : 3    loss: 5.22836971282959      training_acc tensor(0.3235, device='cuda:0')    0m 0s
epoch : 3    loss: 5.224219799041748     training_acc tensor(0.3276, device='cuda:0')    0m 0s
epoch : 3    loss: 5.222436428070068     training_acc tensor(0.3294, device='cuda:0')    0m 1s
epoch : 3    loss: 5.2202887535095215    training_acc tensor(0.3316, device='cuda:0')    0m 1s
```

I don't konw hw to solve this problem

Comment: Have you tried using Binary Cross Entropy instead of Dice loss? Also, it's not very clear what problem you have.

Comment: I think may be my loss function get error,I try to use crossentropyloss, I used network's outputs and label to caculate loss.`loss =criteon(outputs,label) ` where outputs size is [4,224,224] and label size is [4,224,224] .It  get error, I try to use one-hot encoding to transform outputs and label ,but use them to cacualte loss get error too.